# Embedded Tomcat, Jersey, and WebApplicationInitializer not loading

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0, embedded-tomcat-7

I am attempting to embed tomcat in my existing Jersey web application. 
I am able to get Tomcat running no problem, and even loading my JSP's from the webapp dir. The issue is getting it to see my WebApplicationInitializer class like it does in the full container. I'm fairly certain this is a class path issue, if I add a VirtualDirResource and set the context to it, my Jersey app loads. The issue there is, Jersey can no longer load my JSP Viewables. It returns 404. Again, I have no web.xml anywhere. Not sure what code would be helpful, so ask for code samples if you think you have an answer.

Comment: Have you considered using `spring-boot` instead? That would give you the embedded container plus a ton of other features for free.

Comment: I started down that path. I ran into some dependency issues from our parent pom. Also, there are other libraries we use internally that won't run with Spring boot.